# get file names and use them in a multi-choice list

Tags: powershell, list

I want to make a powershell script to rename pdf files from their respective pdftotext lines and/or pdfinfo title. First I want to make a multi-choice list of pdf files in a certain path and pick a pdf file from the list which I want to rename. Could anybody help to  make a choice list from file names may be piped through gci command?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. We are not a "Please write me a script" kind of website. If you share your research, we'll help you figuring out where things are going wrong. Can you edit your post and include your script?

Comment: You will not be able to simply use pipes for that process. It's too complex for that. You will either have to write a CLI interface or use parts of the .NET frameworks for this. What did you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for all comments. Here is my code to rename a pdf file from its respective text or metadata. The code is highly primitive because I am not an IT man; just borrowed and gathered pieces from others.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all comments. Here is my code to rename a pdf file from its respective text or metadata. The code is highly primitive because I am not an IT man; just borrowed and gathered pieces from others.

```
$x = @()

function Read-OpenFileDialog([string]$WindowTitle, [string]$InitialDirectory, [string]$Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*", [switch]$AllowMultiSelect)
{  
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $openFileDialog.Title = $WindowTitle  
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($InitialDirectory)) { $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory }
    $openFileDialog.Filter = $Filter
    if ($AllowMultiSelect) { $openFileDialog.MultiSelect = $false }
    $openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true    # Without this line the ShowDialog() function may hang depending on system configuration and running from console vs. ISE.
    $openFileDialog.ShowDialog() > $null
    if ($AllowMultiSelect) { return $openFileDialog.Filenames } else { return $openFileDialog.Filename }
}
$file = Read-OpenFileDialog -WindowTitle "PDF Dosyası seçin" -InitialDirectory '$path' -Filter "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf"
if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($file)) { Write-Host "You selected the file: $file" }
else { "Dosya seçmediniz" }

$path= "$file"|Split-Path
cd $path

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "VERİ FORMU"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(700,400) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {
$x=$objListbox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()
    }
    })

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,220)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "EVET"



$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)  
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListbox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button  
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,220)  
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)  
$CancelButton.Text = "İPTAL ET"  
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})  
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "LİSTEDEN SEÇİM YAPIN:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox 
$objListbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,840) 

$objListBox.Font = "Arial Black"


pdftotext -eol dos -l 2 $file tmp.txt  
(gc tmp.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content tmp.txt  

$i=pdfinfo "$file" |grep -i title|sed -e 's/Title\:[ ]*//g'  
If (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($i))  
{  
$line6=$i  
}  



$line1= (Get-Content tmp.txt)[0]
$line2= (Get-Content tmp.txt)[1]
$line3= (Get-Content tmp.txt)[2]
$line4= (Get-Content tmp.txt)[3]
$line5= (Get-Content tmp.txt)[4]


[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("$line1")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("$line2")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("$line3")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("$line4")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("$line5")
[void] $objListbox.Items.Add("$line6")



$objListbox.Height =170
$objForm.Controls.Add($objListbox) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()


$z= $objListbox.SelectedItems

if ($z -ne ""){  
$z= $z -replace '[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]',"_"  
$z= $z -replace '[ ]',"_"  
$z= $z -replace '_{2,}',"_"  
$z= $z.Trim() 
Write-Host "dosya $z.pdf olarak kaydedildi"   
rename-item $file -newname $z".pdf" 
}  
Else {Write-Host "isim değişmedi"}  
rm tmp.txt  
pause

$x
```